# How to add additional icons on Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore-client

on Sitecore 8, we have a bunch of icons.
On the ribbon you can select  -> Configure -> Icons. On this dialog, box you can Select a lot of sections like "Applications", "apps" etc. Is it possible to create a new section and add more items?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is "Yes", it is possible. 
All icons are stored as zip archives by the path: `\sitecore\shell\Themes\Standard\` on the disk.

If you want to add your own icons, you need go through the steps below:

> Unfortunately this solution allows us to select created icons only manually. For example: MyIcon/16x16/ChromeLogo.png. But after first usages the icon will appear in the recent tab and it will be easier to use.

1. You need to prepare the icon that you want to add. In my case it is `ChromeLogo.png`. There are some requirements: icon should be square and has transparent background. The icon, idially, should be added in five sizes (but some of them can be skipped): 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48 and 128x128;
2. Prepare the following folder structure:

[image: Icons structure]

3. Place the icons in the corresponding folders (icon with size 16x16 in folder with name 16x16 and etc.);
4. Zip it is all. The name of archive should be the same as the containing folder (MyIcons.zip);
5. Upload the zip file by the path which was mentioned above: `\sitecore\shell\Themes\Standard\`.

Now you will be able to select your newly added icon in the icon selector.

[image: Selecting item manually]

> If you still want to manage the icon by the Change Icon dialog, the Viet Hoang's article shows us how we can achieve that: https://buoctrenmay.wordpress.com/2017/06/17/how-to-inject-the-custom-icons-to-sitecore-8/